# Do you put NSFetchRequest into cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

It seems me somewhat slow to perform `NSFetchRequest` in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`.

How do you treat it? Is it more memory / time efficient to perform it in `viewDidLoad`, cache result into a dictionary, and use that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be as fast as possible. You don't want fetch requests running in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea due to performance reasons, as @Paulw11 mentioned in his comment. Additionaly, you will execute fetch requests more times than it's actually needed (while scrolling the table view back and forth), because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called each time a cell is reused.

I would recommend using [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/). It is designed specifically to show Core Data records in `UITableView`. It allows batch fetching (doesn't fetch all the objects, but only the ones that need to be displayed). Also you will be able to easily track changes in your model.